# Ошибка: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код:

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\Админ\\Desktop\\1234.py')
```

При запуске он выдаёт ошибку:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

При этом, раньше у меня получалось создать файл через open, даже не указывая полный путь, вот так:

```
file = open('1234.py')
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Версия Python какая?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 3.8

Comment: попробуй file = open('C:/Users/Админ/Desktop/1234.py'). Вместо двух бэк слэша используйте форвард слэш

Comment: наверно ты перетащил файл в другое место

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию у `open` стоит режим чтения `mode='r'`, для создания файла надо прямо указать например режим записи `mode='w'` или режим добавления `mode='a'`

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\Админ\\Desktop\\1234.py', 'w')
```